# Android POST without using NameValuePair

Tags: android, networking, post

how can I post data without using `NameValuePair`?

I want to post String
In JS, I would use:

```
var separator = String.fromCharCode(0xef, 0xbf, 0xbf);
var postUrl = "PostUrl";
var postData = "3" + separator + "0" + separator + "13"
network.setUnicode(true);
this.reply = network.post(postUrl, postData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold the [HTTP Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) that comes with Android.  In your case, you'll want to use a [`StringEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) as the payload of your POST request.

```
public void postString(URI uri, String yourDataString) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(yourDataString));

    client.execute(post);
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to do more careful checking for error conditions and suchlike.

Answer (score 1):

```
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataOutputStream outStream;
    DataInputStream inStream;

    // Build request body
    String body = "3" + separator + "0" + separator + "13"

    // Create connection
    url = new URL("http://www.site.com");
    urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    ((HttpURLConnection)urlConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ body.length());

    // Create I/O streams
    outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    // Send request
    outStream.writeBytes(body);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    // Get Response
    String buffer;
    while((buffer = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }

    // Close I/O streams
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```

Comment: Hm, i haven't used this URLConnection, DataStreams yet, but seems to work. Thanks

Comment: what is saprator in this

Answer (score 0):

Construct URL something like below. That should work.

```
 http://www.site.com?postData=3&separator=0&anotherParam=value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid","123"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date","2012"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op","update"));
            try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myurl.com/action/put/newrecord");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
            }
```

I use this method to post data in android / Java. However, I think this is the right way!

Comment: Eh... I know this method. I said it have to be without pairs :)

Comment: mmmmm Bro, I know this way because you can authenticate too :) However, try by making a `URL` with your parameters.